# Detecting VM Copied / Replicated

Tags: replication, virtual-machine

I am looking to detect any unique constraint if and when a VM image is copied from one location to another. I am actually doing this as a part of product licensing service modification to prevent license tampering. The licensing service uses MAC ID to uniquely identify a license. This works fine on physical machine but in case of a copied VM licensing service is unable to identify the OS as separate OS and invoke license blocking. I only need any unique element which gets changed when VM is copied / replicated.
(I have omitted details for over simplification). 
Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: You might founder your licensing scheme on a wrong assumption, as a MAC address is not unalterable and can be changed in a physical machine... For the virtualization detection, there are plenty articles online addressing the point.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of to approach this is to have a licensing server. When you enter a license code into the client (on a VM), it contacts the server and sends it its license code and other information. It contacts it repeatedly (you define the interval -- maybe once every few hours) asking 'Am I still valid"? Along with this request, it sends a unique ID. The server replies 'Yes, you are valid', and sends a *new* unique ID back to the client. The client sends this unique ID back with its next request to the server.

If the VM is duplicated, the next time it asks the server 'Am I valid?', the unique ID will be incorrect either for it, or for the other VM. Both will not continue to work.

You will need to determine what to do if the server goes down, or the network goes down, such that the client cannot communicate with the server. Do you immediately disable your software? Bad idea! Don't make your customers angry. You'll want to give them a grace period. How long should this be? A few days? Weeks?

Let's say you give them a 1-month grace period. In theory, they could clone the parent VM just after entering the license key, then restore the other VMs to this clone just before their grace period runs out, disabling network access to them. This would be a hassle for your customers though, just to have pirated additional copies of your software. You have to determine what kind of grace period won't hassle your legitimate customers, while hopefully giving you the protection you seek.

Additional protection could be achieved by verifying that the VM's clock is set correctly. This would prevent the above approach to pirating.

Another consideration is that a savvy user could write their own licensing server to communicate with the VM instances, and tell them all 'you're good' -- so encrypting the communication could help deter this. How far you want to go here really depends on how much you think pirating really might be an issue with your customers. In the end you won't be able to stop true pirates who have time on their hands, but you can keep honest users honest.